# Unable to Modal popup close link not click in selenium using java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing issue to close the modal popup link using selenium in java.

I have used below code for this.

```
 Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'No Thank')]")).click();
```

HTML of the modal popup and error stack trace of the Getting error : invisible element

Please help on this , I have google a lot but not successful to do that.

Note: The link I could not share with you due to VPN

Comment: Try Adding some wait between switchTo().activeElement(); and clicking the No Thanks button. Just add Thread.sleep(3000) in between to test it.

Comment: It's not a good idea to share image, though you can not share the link , please share the image of model link and HTML.

Comment: @BikashRanjan Update the question with the HTML of the `modal popup` and error stack trace of the _Getting error : invisible element_

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks updated.

Comment: @PJAutomator , I have checked as per you mentioned like   below but getting no such as element found.
driver.switchTo().activeElement();Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'No Thank')]")).click();

Comment: @BikashRanjan HTML still missing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Thread.sleep` you want to use `WebDriverWait.until`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'No Thank')]"))).click();
```

This way we can assure that the element you are trying to interact with is visible

Comment: without switching the focus of driver , he/she may not be able to interact with the model box.